# check data and retrieve value from database in php in click in textbox

Tags: php, mysql, database

i have a database with these field
   member id(mid),sponsor id(sid) ,sponsor name(sname)

[image]

and a joining form like as

[image]

now i want to add this feature when i type a sponsor id then its tell me this id is available in database or not ...and if not available then it show message front of this field and if yes , then when i click in sponsor name field its automatically fill the name of sponser of this id ..and i want all this happened before click submit button..thanks..

Comment: ajax pass sponsor id to php, then check db data exist , then pass result to html ,then change textbox..

Comment: i have no idea how ajax handle this,please give any tutorial..

Answer (score 0):

Please use the JQuery validate plugin for this. Below is the example that how to use remote function in this plugin.

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote